# Laravel Controller: "for" loop getting value of first iteration only

Tags: php, laravel

Apologies for asking this but i can't seem to find the solution to my problem. I have the code below:

```
for($x=0; $x<=2; $x++){
            $users = User::where('division', 1)
            ->where('has_been_assigned', null)
            ->first();

            $assignedLead = NewLeads::where('pic_endorsed_to', null)
            ->first();

            $assignedLead->pic_endorsed_to = $users->id;
            $assignedLead->save();

        }
```

So in my MySQL NewLeads table, im hoping to achieve this (assigning a lead to a user, then the next lead to the next user and so on):

```
id     pic_endorsed_to (FKEY)
 1                         1
 2                         2
 3                         3
```

Instead i get this:

```
 id     pic_endorsed_to (FKEY)
  1                         1
  2                         1
  3                         1
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the desired result?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is use of loop ? in $assignedLead and $users query you are fetching one and same record ?

Comment: Hello, $assignedLead fetches the Leads (or you can say "Tasks") collection while $users accesses the User collection to fetch the user to be assigned to the "lead" or "task".

Comment: Oh you were asking about the use of loop. My goal is to fetch one record after another as many as the number of iterations set.

Comment: you are not updating user. so in every iteration there's the same user. and what if there's no user to assign to??

Comment: Hello, i can create a validation for that.  But i'm still in the process of assigning users to the leads/tasks. But as you can see, i'm having trouble assigning one user after another because the for loop only gets the value of the first user and not the next two.

Comment: @miguban Is it a one time task or will it be done frequently on your site? If done frequently, how are you treating already assigned leads' rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs. Seems like zahid's comment solved my current problem:

> you are not updating user. so in every iteration there's the same user. and what if there's no user to assign to?? – zahid hasan emon

Just had to flag/update the user's status with "assigned".

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity using the code provided by OP (at the time I am writing):

```
   $users = User::where('division', 1)
        ->where('has_been_assigned', null)
        ->get();
   foreach ($users as $user){
    $assignedLead = NewLeads::where('pic_endorsed_to', null)
        ->first();
    if(assignedLead){
        $assignedLead->pic_endorsed_to = $users->id;
        $assignedLead->save();
    }else{ break; }
   }
```

All I am doing here is just fetching the user and assigning those user's id to the NewLeads whose value is null.

In every loop, it will fetch the first row with pic_endorsed_to null and update the value to the user's id.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are not using the $x anywhere inside the loop to make it dynamic.
Either use the $x in somewhere condition as per requirement or remove first.

Answer (score 0):

You are running `->first();` everytime without any dynamic condition on where clause, so it will fetch only `first` record again and again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change `->first()` to `->get()`.

Then check this line, and change it with the code given below:

```
where('pic_endorsed_to', null)
            ->first();
```

it should be like

```
where('pic_endorsed_to', $mydetail)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this way.

> solution 1:

```
return collect($models->items())->each(function ($item, $index){
            if( $item->quoteReturnDetail){  echo  $item ;  exit(); }   });
```

> Solution 2

```
   return collect($models->items())->each(function ($item, $index){
            if( index === 2 ){  echo  $item ;  exit(); }   });
```